# aggregate data at factor varaible level

Tags: aggregate, numeric

I have a data-frame with "ID" variable and other numeric variables. On importing data r is taking  "ID" variable as **factor variable**.

I want to aggregate other variables at ID level and trying

aggregate(dataset, by = list(dataset$id), FUN=sum)

Problem:

Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Please help in - how to aggregate numeric data by factor variables.

Dataset below:

id  x   y   z

a1  1   NA  NA
a1  2   NA  NA
a1  3   3   3
b2  1   4   5
b2  1   45  6
c3  NA  5   NA
c3  NA  6   6
c3  8   2   1
c3  5   6   0

Answer (score 0):

after online search and several tries, i get the solution -

df <- aggregate((t1[,2:4]), by = list(t1$id), FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE)